# How to set ARM user app start address when using USB bootloader?

Tags: arm, embedded, bootloader, cortex-m

Just picked up one of these ARM Cortex-M3 [LPC1768 mini boards](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=260848402688) from eBay. It's basically a breakout board.

However, based on what little documentation came with it, I've determined that it has a USB bootloader similar to that described by NXP's 
[LPC1700 secondary USB bootloader (AN10866)](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10866.pdf) app note.

Both docs *(the app note and board docs)* indicate that user programs are to be built such that their **starting address is 0x2000**. *Because the USB bootloader is already at 0x0 and takes up 8K*.

Both docs also show screenshots (see page 14 of app note) on how to do this within Keil uVision, however I'm planning on using a GNU toolchain (Yagarto + Eclipse + OpenOCD).

How do I specify a **starting address of 0x2000** when compiling with a GNU toolchain so that it will work properly with the USB bootloader?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have lots of arm based examples:

https://github.com/dwelch67

Find or create your own linker script. where it might have said ORIGIN = 0x00000000 for the rom change that to 0x2000, something like this for example:

```
MEMORY
{
   rom : ORIGIN = 0x00002000, LENGTH = 0x6000
   ram : ORIGIN = 0x40000000, LENGTH = 0x2000
}
SECTIONS
{
   .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
   .bss  : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

you might want/need a .data with

```
   .data  : { *(.data*) } > ram AT >rom
```

or something like that.  depends on your programs and boot code and all that.

If you already have a working system that builds for 0x00000000 then find the linkerscript being used and make a copy of it and change it to 0x2000 and specify that linker script.

Comment: let me know how you like that board, I might one/few myself.

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right path; found a working "hello world" example that works with the NXP secondary bootloader: http://code.google.com/p/cortex-m3-tutorials/downloads/detail?name=LEDBlinky-forNEXP_SecondaryUSBLoader.rar