# How to get info register work in GDB with OpenOCD

Tags: c, gdbserver, openocd

I am brand new to OpenOCD and GDB so kindly bear with me. I run my OpenOCD in server in Screen1  which is talking to a system. In Screen 1 I am waiting for the connection to come:

```
Info: JTAG tap:some abcd: CPU enabled
```

In Screen2, I start `gdb` and then

```
(gdb) target remote localhost:2001
```

I get in Screen1 (openocd):

```
accepting gdb connection from 2001
```

This works fine then I get a bunch of error messages like:

```
Error: Target running halt it first.
```

Why should I get this. All I did was connect. All I want to do is to type `info reg` at the gdb prompt and get the register values.

Question1: How do you reliably halt the system? What is the command. If I keep doing

```
c
stop
CTRl-C
```

most of the time info reg is all zero but once in a while I get the valid values.
What would be the guaranteed of halting the processor and read the registers.

Comment: In gist, all I need is a reliable way of halting the system and reading the register using gdb. When I hit CTRL-C sometime it halts most of the time gdb says ^CQuit and does not halt. So I guess hitting CTRL-C is contextual.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917003/eclipse-gdb-init-and-run-settings-for-arm-lpc1768-using-openocd

Answer (score 0):

You should have `-c 'reset halt'` in your openocd command argument.

Or, you can type `reset halt` either from gdb or at your openocd prompt if you connect to your openocd via telnet.

**From GDB**

```
(gdb) monitor reset halt
```

**From Telnet**

Add `-c 'telnet_port 4444'` to you openocd command, then from another terminal, run `telnet localhost 4444`.

```sh
$ telnet localhost 4444
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Open On-Chip Debugger
> reset halt
```